# Using LIKE statement for filtering

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Im using this code to filter my table:

```
Table.Filtered := False;
Table.Filter := '[' + Field_Search + '] LIKE ''%' + Edit_Search.Text + '%''';
Table.Filtered := True;
```

but it raises this exception:

> "Operation not applicable."

where is problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `TTable.Filter` isn't a SQL query. `LIKE` isn't supported (neither is `IN`). The supported operators are `=`, `<>`, `>`, `<`, `>=`, '<=`,`AND`,`NOT`and`OR`, according to [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Setting_the_Filter_Property)

For more complicated filtering, use the [TDataSet.OnFilterRecord](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.OnFilterRecord) event:

```
procedure TForm1.Table1FilterRecord(Dataset: TDataset; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  // Don't remember if D7 supports DataSet[FieldName] syntax; if not,
  // use DataSet.FieldByName instead, or a persistent field.
  Accept := Pos(Edit_Search.Text, DataSet[SearchField].AsString) > 0;
end;
```

Comment: LIKE is supported in dataset filters.  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Filter

Comment: It's not, according to the [list of supported logical operators](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Setting_the_Filter_Property)

Comment: I think Ken is right.  The like operator is supported by some databases, such as DBISAM (TDBISAMTable), but not TTable.

Comment: You're right.  When using the BDE, TTable doesn't support LIKE in filters and gives the same message that the OP reported.  He would either need to use another dataset or use a clientdataset with his current setup.

Comment: @Bruce: Or use the code I posted in my answer, which doesn't require as much work as changing to another dataset or a clientdataset.

Comment: great tip, and for a field by name, e.g. for oracledataset it will be like this:
DataSet.FieldByName('FIELD_NAME').Value

Answer (score 4):

```
Table.Filtered := False;
Table.Filter := Field_Search + ' LIKE ' + QuotedStr('*' + Edit_Search.Text + '*');
Table.Filtered := True;
```

Comment: You should add some details to your answer!

Answer (score 3):

you should use this :

```
   DataModule.Table.Filtered := False;
   DataModule.Table.Filter := 'Field_Name' + ' LIKE ' + QuotedStr(Edt_SearchByCode.Text +'%');
   DataModule.Table.Filtered := True;
```

and will work like a Magic and no use of TQuery any more ....
and if you want Matching does not take case-sensitivity into account.
you should use this code instead:

```
   DataModule.Table.Filtered := False;
   DataModule.Table.FilterOptions := [foCaseInsensitive];
   DataModule.Table.Filter := 'Field_Name' + ' LIKE ' + QuotedStr(Edt_SearchByCode.Text +'%');
   DataModule.Table.Filtered := True;
```

Answer (score 1):

The following Code will work as **Like** as well:

```
if Edit1.Text <>'' then
begin
Query1.Filter :='FieldName ='+quotedstr('*'+ edit1.Text +'*');
Query1.Filtered:=true;
end
else
begin query1.Filtered :=false; end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this topic looking for something else. I always use the TDataSet.OnFilterRecord event, and in most cases I use a TEdit.OnChange event so the search is "Active";

```
var
Criteria : string;
...
...

procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Table.Filtered := False;
  Criteria := Edit1.text;
  Table.Filtered := True;
end;
```

and with the OnFilter event

```
procedure TForm1.TableFilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet;
  var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept := AnsiContainsStr(Table.Fields[xx].asString,Criteria);
end;
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using mostly with TEdit here is the code

```
if (EditSerarch.Text <> '') then
begin
FDQQuery.Filtered := false;
FDQQuery.Filter:=   'Name LIKE'+ QuotedStr('%'+EditSerarch.Text+'%') +
            ' OR Company LIKE '+ QuotedStr('%'+EditSerarch.Text+'%') +
              ' OR Phone LIKE '+ QuotedStr('%'+EditSerarch.Text+'%') +
             ' OR Mobile LIKE '+ QuotedStr('%'+EditSerarch.Text+'%');
FDQQuery.Filtered:= True;
end else FDQQuery.Filtered := false;
```

Comment: @kobik:  Oops, my mistake, comment deleted.  Thanks]

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to use a SQL Query to perform this operation.

Example:

```
query1.SQL.Text:='Select * FROM table_name WHERE field like '+ QuotedStr(edit1.text+'%');
query1.Active:=true;
```