# Using LIKE and '%'  in an ADO dataset filter

Tags: delphi, ado

I have a problem when trying to apply a filter to a ADO dataset in Delphi XE2 ...

```
Filter := ' [Name] like ''%john'' ';
```

It raises an exception:

```
Project Test.exe raised exception class EOleException with message 
'Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, 
or are in conflict with one another'. Process stopped.
```

but when using:

```
Filter := ' [Name] like ''john%'' '
```

it works fine!

why?

Comment: What does `works fine` mean?  Can you give an example of both broken and working?

Comment: I mean, I did not get an error

Comment: So the actual code that doesn't work is `Filter := '[Name] like ''%john'''`?

Comment: Have you tried replacing % with * instead?

Comment: @JamesL. Yes! it doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnEasley Yes i tested that doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you don't have any `Name` columns that end in `john`?

Comment: @KenWhite No! it raises an exception

Comment: "I have a problem" - what is the problem ? "I did not get an error" - what is an error ? http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: If "it raises an exception", it should say that in your question, along with the **exact error message, including error codes or memory addresses**. We can't read your mind or see your screen from here. We only know what you tell us. If you want help, give us the information to use to help you.

Comment: I added exception to my question

Comment: I don't know if that applies to recent ADO versions, nor whether the topicstarter uses contemporary ADO. *Note that using a wildcard character as the first character in the string criteria of a LIKE clause is not supported. You may only use a wildcard character as the ending character, or as both the beginning and ending character, of the criteria of a LIKE cause for an ADO Filter.* http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181487 and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/226119

Comment: @Arioch'The now what can i do?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937730 - MDAC version checker

Comment: Maybe you can update ADO/MDAC to 2.8sp1 version.
Maybe you can use some data-server specific tricks like copying last 4 letters of Name into a separate column.
Maybe you can move that condition into SQL SELECT WHERE clause and re-open the query. 
Maybe there is event-handler like TBDEDataSet.OnFilterRecord where you can calculate all you want in Delphi.
Or maybe you can do nothing.

Comment: @hassan - Try directly retrieving filtered data with sql, i.e. `Query.SQL.Text := 'select * from [table] where [name] like ''%john''';`

Comment: Filter:= ' [Name] like '+ QuotedStr('%john');

Comment: @Ravaut123 Do you test it?
i belive that: `Filter:= ' [Name] like '+ QuotedStr('%john');` = `Filter := ' [Name] like ''%john'' ';`

Comment: Would it not be Select * from [table] Where [name] Like '"%john%"'

Comment: @GlenMorse 1) of course not, read some docs on SQL LIKE. 2) You can see in the questio nthat your variant does work, it is just not what needed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using LIKE statement for filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594724/using-like-statement-for-filtering)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Operator can only be one of the following:
=   <   >   <=   >=   <>   LIKE
If you use the LIKE operator, you can also use the * or % wildcards as the last character in the string or as the first and last character in the string.

http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ado/quickref/recordset_filter.html

You can catch the filter on the event OnFilterRecord:

```
procedure TForm1.ADODataSet1FilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet; var Accept: Boolean);
var
  iPos: Integer;
begin
  iPos:= pos('john',ADODataSet1name.AsString);
  if (iPos>0) and
     (iPos = length(ADODataSet1name.AsString)-3) then
  begin
    Accept:= True;
  end
  else
  begin
    Accept:= False;
  end;
end;
```

or

```
function TForm1.IsLastCriteria(AText: String): Boolean;
var
  iPos: Integer;
begin
  iPos:= pos(AText,ADODataSet1name.AsString);
  Result:= (iPos>0) and
           (iPos = length(ADODataSet1name.AsString)-length(AText)-1);
end;

procedure TForm1.ADODataSet1FilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept:= IsLastCriteria('john');
end;
```

Comment: +1. BTW, `Accept := (iPos>0) and ...` reads better IMHO, without the `if`.

Comment: @kobik: Yep, I know. But I likes the if then ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

AS. I still ask you to read http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise and describe your environment accordingly.

- What is database server ?
- What version are MDAC/ADO components?
- What the query is ?
- What is Name column type in SQL ?

You are "upping" the comments, that si nice. But you don't answer the questions. And that is not nice. We are not ESPers, we canot read you mind.

I put you few suggestions in comments above. Did you tried them ? Did they worked ? To quote them:

1. Maybe you can update ADO/MDAC to 2.8sp1 version. Referenced MSDN KB articles are told to apply to MDAC up to 2.7 version. Maybe 2.8sp1 no more has that limitation.
2. Maybe you can use some data-server specific tricks like copying last 4 letters of Name into a separate column.
3. Maybe you can move that condition into SQL SELECT WHERE clause and re-open the query.
4. Maybe there is event-handler like TBDEDataSet.OnFilterRecord

There are 4 workarounds and you either did not tried them or did not reported the results. Not nice.

- Idea #1 is self-explanatory
- Idea #3 was detailed by @SertacAkyuz as far as he could do it, giving lack of information about your program.
- Idea #4 was detailed  by @Ravaut123
- Idea #2 is outlined below

Assuming your "ADO database" is backed by Microsoft Access, and according to http://www.databasedev.co.uk/access-sql-string-functions.html ...
Or using MS SQL and according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx ...
Or...

Query.SQL.Text := 'select **Right(Name, 4) as name_tail,** * from table where ...'

See that extra column added to query! 4 is length for "john" there.

With query like that the following filtering conditions are to be equivalent:

- Filter := ' [Name] like ''%john'' ';
- Filter := ' [name_tail] = ''john'' ';

However, if on some rows Name column is shorter than 4 letters, i don't know what RIGHT function would do. Maybe it will truncate the result, or maybe throw an error and abort the query. The latter maybe - depending on the real data - maybe can be alleviated by padding with spaces to the 4 length like

```
LTrim(Right('    ' || Name, 4)) as name_tail
```

That is for you to test, since only you know the details of your environment.

Comment: Oh! Thank, I'm so sorry :(
In Delphi i use ADOTable and this components dont support SQL commands.
So i changed to ADOQuery component and use SQL commands to do this filter.
---------
Your idea is perfect and complete but they need SQL commands and that component would support.

I'm sorry! My English is poor.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer to this question was mentioned in comments.
If you used asterisk instead of percent symbol, everything would work great
Filter := ' [Name] like ''*john'' ';